# asp.net mvc app and windows service: share view logic

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, view

I have an **asp.net mvc** project and a **windows service** project. They use the same business layer project. I get list of some items from database and render them in mvc project (view logic (with links and some icons) is in razor view). Now I have a requirement to send the same ui for this items by email periodically from windows service. I think to move ui logic in BL is a bad idea. How to share ui logic between windows service and mvs project?

Comment: Can't your Windows service just make HTTP calls to your web application and use this to populate your email body? Main issue I can see is that email clients are notoriously bad at rendering HTML.

Comment: It sounds strange for me. To implement it I need server-server authentication like HMAC or smth like this. And this API will return HTML markup and not just data. Intuitively I want to share view logic between projects. But now I'm thinking about right solution.